# Set preselected value in Select2 4.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I´ve already read a lot and tried different things but I´m unable to preselect a value on a select2 AJAX dropdown.

It´s **Version 4.0.0** so initSelect isn´t available any more. Also adding the  manuall via jQuery isn´t working.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this issue? Documentation is a bit rare on this topic.

Thanks a lot,
Michael

Comment: please share relevant code that you have tried so far, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - that solves the problem. Haven´t found this tutorial before...